# Block interface until operation is done

Tags: objective-c, ios5, cocos2d-iphone

I have a login method that connects to a server to check the user info when the user clicks on the login button.

How can i block the view showing an activity indicator so that the user does not click on the button again?

Comment: How are you doing the login?  An asynchronous `NSURLConnection` or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just set the `userInteractionEnabled` to false for the button?

```
btn.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

and set it back to YES after the login is completed?

You can set this property to every responsive UI element in the view you wish to disable.

**BTW**

This off-curse dose not prevent you from showing an activity indicator.

As always I love to recommend [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)

**EDIT**
If you are getting ARC errors do this:

1. Select your target
2. Look for the MBProgressHud.m file in the "Build Phases" -> "Compile Sources"
3. add `-fno-objc-arc` in the Compiler Flags of the MBProgressHud.m file.

This will flash xCode not to compile this file with ARC.

Comment: i believe that MBProgressHUD dos not work on iOS 5 and Xcode 4.2 :( any solution?