# MBProgressHUD Block interface until operation is done

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios5, ios4, mbprogresshud

I need to block the interface until the `MBProgressHUD` operation is done. I did refer this thread,

[Block interface until operation is done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628981/block-interface-untill-operation-is-done)

According to it, we should disable each individual item which wont work for me. My case is I need to disable user from clicking back button. I did try `HUD.userInteractionEnabled = YES` which disable every controller except the back button. Is there any way of blocking user from popping out from that controller?

Regards,
Dilshan

Comment: Add HUD to Window instead of View.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if u dont find a proper way to do that, you can ignore the whole user interaction by

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

.U can stop this by

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

Answer (score 11):

You can add the MBProgressHUD to the navigation controller's view so that it also prevents interaction with the back button:

```
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.navigationController.view animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want a particular control to make enable when HUD is displaying , you can simply add the line `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourControl];`  in your `showHUD` method as

```
-(void) showHUD:(UIView *)view
{

    if (self.HUDdisplayed == NO)
    {
        self.HUDdisplayed = YES;
        HUD = [[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES] retain];
    }
//    HUD.delegate = self;
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:HUD];
     [self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourControl];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I add the `MBProgressHUD` to my view and it blocks all input until it is removed:

```
MBProgressHUD HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
HUD.opacity = 0.7f;

[self.view addSubview:HUD];

HUD.delegate = self;
[HUD show:YES];
```

**Note:** `self` is the view controller the HUD is being add to

Answer (score 0):

@sujith1406's answer is correct. However, the methods he mentioned are deprecated from iOS 13. Here is my protocol based solution to implement MBProgressHUD blocking.

```
import Foundation
import MBProgressHUD

protocol AppLoader {
    func showLoader()
    func hideLoader()
}

extension AppLoader where Self: UIViewController {
    func showLoader() {
        let views: [UIView?] = [self.navigationController?.view, view]
        views.forEach({ $0?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false })
        MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
    }
    
    func hideLoader() {
        let views: [UIView?] = [self.navigationController?.view, view]
        views.forEach({ $0?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true })
        MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
    }
}

extension UIViewController: AppLoader {}
```

how to use it?

```
func fetchUserInformation() {
   self.showLoader()
   //perform api call. assuming fetchUserData is an api that fetches a particular user data from the server.
   self.fetchUserData(completion: { [weak self] in 
       self?.hideLoader()
   })
}
```